# yq - How to keep only certains keys in a (nested) object?

Tags: yq

I have a bunch of Kubernetes resources (i.e. a lot of yaml files), and I would like to have a result with only certain paths.

My current brutal approach looks like:

```
cat my-list-of-deployments | yq eval 'select(.kind == "Deployment") \
| del(.metadata.labels, .spec.replicas, .spec.selector, .spec.strategy, .spec.template.metadata) \
| del(.spec.template.spec.containers.[0].env, del(.spec.template.spec.containers.[0].image))' -
```

Of course this is super inefficient.

In the path `.spec.template.spec.containers.[0]` I actually want ideally delete anything except: `.spec.template.spec.containers.[*].image` and `.spec.template.spec.containers.[*].resources` (where "*" means, keep all array elements).

I tried something like

```
del(.spec.template.spec.containers.[0] | select(. != "name"))
```

But this did not work for me. **How can I make this better?**

---

Example input:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-one
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: app-one:0.2.0
          name: app-one
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: http
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 512Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-two
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: redis:3.2-alpine
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - redis-cli
                - info
                - server
            periodSeconds: 20
          name: app-two
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - redis-cli
                - ping
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
          startupProbe:
            periodSeconds: 2
            tcpSocket:
              port: 6379
```

Desired output:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-one
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-one
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 512Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-two
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-two
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
```

Comment: did the answer below work out for you?

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use the [`with_entries` function](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select#use-select-and-with_entries-to-filter-map-keys) inside the `.containers` array to manually mark the required fields - `name`, `resources` and use the [`|=` update operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update#relative-form-or) to put the modified result back

```
yq eval '
  select(.kind == "Deployment").spec.template.spec.containers[] |=
    with_entries( select(.key == "name" or .key == "resources") ) ' yaml
```